# how to get all object inside rooms on sails.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

i want join room and get all object inside it.

example on my controller :

```
var user = {name: "jimmy", email: "jimmy@local.com"};
sails.sockets.join(req.socket, "login_users");
sails.sockets.broadcast("login_users", user);
```

how to get all object user inside room login_users?, my expected result :

```
result = {name: "jimmy", email: "jimmy@local.com"}
```

Comment: Please show your approach and where you got stuck. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try to throw this out to the Sails.js Gitter page. Might get some help there too. [Gitter Page](https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails)